# Просмотр исходного файла

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Как можно посмотреть исходный файл после компиляции? Хотелось бы посмотреть, как выстраиваются `template` функции. Есть что-то похожее на ключ `/P`, но только после компиляции?

Comment: Посмотрите asm :)

Comment: @Harry я бы хотел именно посмотреть какие аргументы и как итд выставляются в template

Comment: Не думаю, что какой-то компилятор генерирует промежуточный *С++* код...

Comment: https://cppinsights.io ?

Comment: *"Какие аргументы выставляются в template"* и *"как выстраиваются template функции"* - это очень разные пожелания.